# Xamarin Forms Webview not playing video

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a webview declared in Xamarin Forms Xaml.  Whether I set the source in code behind or in Xaml, the video control renders fine, but when you click the play icon it does not play.  I can skip ahead and back by tapping the bottom seek bar that renders.  The video will skip ahead and freeze on a frame, but still wont play when tapping play.  I'm setting the source of the webview to an html5 video tag as its the closest I could get to getting a video to render.  I should mention that the video is formatted for streaming using Azure Media Services, so that shouldn't be the issue.

```
<WebView IsVisible="{Binding HasVideo}" Margin="10,0,0,0" BindingContextChanged="WebView_BindingContextChanged"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="350"  />

private void WebView_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var webView = ((WebView)sender);

    Post post = (Post)webView.BindingContext;
    if (post.HasVideo)
    {             
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        htmlSource.Html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
                            <html>
                            <body>
                                <video  src='" + post.MainVideoURL + @"' controls width='320' height='240' preload='metadata'   >
                            </ body >
                            </html><style>
                            video {
                                object-fit: fill;
                            }
                            </style>";
        webView.Source = htmlSource;
        }          
    }
```

Comment: Is the `BuildAction` of the video set to `EmbeddedResource` ?

Comment: The video is an internet URL, to a streaming endpoint.  thanks

Comment: oh, i see, did you try to add it like an `<iframe></iframe>` ?

Comment: Do you mean within the html wrap the video tag in an iframe?

Comment: no, i mean that you change the `video` by an `iframe` tag [HTML <iframe> Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: try to close your `video` tag. Btw i think its better to use a mediaplayer (there are some nuget out there) or a custom renderer instead a webview

Comment: @PatrickGoode : Hope it helps. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92018/play-video-in-xamarin-form-cross-platform-pcl-using-webview

Answer (score 3):

It happened for me also, on already installed app. A user reported this problem.

On Android:
When you click the play icon it doesn't play. I can skip ahead and back by tapping the bottom seek bar, or by tapping left/right on the video, it shows different frames.

On iOS:
With the latest update 12.2, the videos stopped working. They show blank background and they don't respond to any click.

I am also using video tag...

Comment: @PatricGoode, Android resolved by clearing the cache of the app.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean clearing the cache of the app

Comment: @PatricGoode:

I meant like this. This solved the video issue for me for Android. 
Open the Settings of your phone.; Tap the Storage heading to open its settings page; Tap the Other Apps heading to see a list of your installed apps.; Find the application you want to clear the cache of and tap its listing.; Tap the Clear cache button.

Comment: clearing the app cache is not solving the problem, it is postponed until next time for me.

Comment: @AnaKochevska Did you find a solution for iOS?

Comment: @HemersonVarela, adding this to the web view in iOS helped me play the video: 
```this.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false; this.AllowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true;```