# webview xamarin forms does not play video on redicted website (ios and android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently using a web view to load some urls,I client reported that when clicking on an item on my menu and the webview is triggered and goes to one of their pages the video they have embedded on their page does not play.

Am I missing something basic here? eg permissions or is it a limitation of the webview?

also one of their links uses "#whatever" at the end and is meant to scrolldown and  loading the page, but does not work. Is this supported?

many thanks

Comment: can you share that video url which Video can't not load in web view ?

Comment: You can try to open the urls with OpenBrowser from Xamarin.Essentials.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=android

Comment: @lalitMaheshwari  Hi sorry only happens in ios . I will put together a small demo because that goes to a link i cannot disclose (client stuff) so. bit weird unless I am missing some permission. I am using xamarin essentails

Comment: Do you refere to this ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/video-player/web-videos If size of video is large , this for ios will need more time to preload.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT  just found this  same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550975/xamarin-forms-webview-not-playing-video  .. No solution though

Comment: @developer9969
can you please add 
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
 <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
 <dict>
  <key>www.the-domain-name.com</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
   <string>TLSv1.0</string>
   <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
   <false/>
   <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
   <true/>
   <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
   <true/>
  </dict>
 </dict>
</dict> this code in info.plist
you can also referred https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats

Comment: @developer9969 Okey , if be issue , you can submit in here (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) .And later hope you can share the link in here :)

Comment: @lalitMaheshwari i already got that code in my info list

Comment: @developer9969 can you please check copy that video url and paste in safari browser and check it's play or not ?

Comment: @lalitMaheshwari yes it plays in safari.. I will better investigate and put a sample together and take it from there.many thanks